# Julia 1.0.0 parse function overflow error seems strange

Tags: julia

There may be an easy answer that I am missing, but I do not see a reason for the following:

```
# Everything works as expected for 2^18
julia> 2^18
262144
julia> 2^18 < typemax(Int64)
true
julia> parse(Int64, bitstring(2^18))
1000000000000000000

# However, 2^19 seems to cause trouble with the parse function.    
julia> 2^19
524288
julia> 2^19 < typemax(Int64)
true
julia> parse(Int64, bitstring(2^19))
ERROR: OverflowError: overflow parsing "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Checking whether `2^18 < typemax(Int64)`doesn't do much good. Even if it overflows, the check will still be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parse` by default parses the given string as a base-10 integer. So your first `parse` gives 10^18 and not 2^18. There is no overflow because `10^18 < typemax(Int64)` is true. However, 10^19 is larger than the maximum of Int64 type. So naturally it overflows.

If the behavior you want is to parse the string as a binary number then add `base = 2` keyword argument to your function call.

```
parse(Int64, bitstring(2^19), base=2)
>>> 524288
```

Otherwise, if you want to parse it as a base-10 number, then try `BigInt` or `Int128` instead of `Int64` in order to avoid overflow.

Comment: Wow, that is a great answer.  Thanks!